# How to dump log messages into a separate text file Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How can I dump all the logs message showing in the terminal into a separate text file?
I am using Selenium with Python and Chrome web driver.

[image: logs]

Comment: if you run it as `python script.py > file.txt` then it should save it in `file.txt`. Eventually it would need to redirect `stderr` also to file - on linux you could do `python script.py > file.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you get these messages but using Google I found  in Chromedriver documentation [Logging](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging) and it uses settings like this to save some logs in file `log.txt`

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_args=["--log-path=log.txt"])
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_args=["--log-path=log.txt", "--verbose"])

#driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

---

**BTW:** in doc shows that normally it sends to `stderr` so using `2> log.txt` should also works.

Comment: It did work but for some strange reasons, it's also printing the input text inside the text file which should be displayed on the terminal.

Comment: I don't know what inputerd text you mean - you didn't show code in question. Using redirection you could get in file text normally displayed in terminal because to display text it uses `stdout` and redirection `> log.txt` sends it to file. But in this answer I don't use redirection.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to run it manually in terminal and redirect `stdout` (standar output) to file

```
python script.py > output.txt
```

It may need also redirect `stderr` (standard error output) to file

```
python script.py > output.txt 2> error.txt
```

or redirect both to the same file

```
python script.py > output.txt 2>&1
```

---

This method works with all programs which display something in terminal.

Comment: well I tried this method but it's printing the input text in the text file and not the logs and error. Is there any other way?

Comment: Did you run it manually in terminal?  Did you use `2>&1` ? It may sends logs on standard error and then you have to redirect `2>`

Answer (score -1):

With Try/except statements you get the error message as a variable.